# How to load data into Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, fetch-api

I have an API endpoint for https on localhost that's serving raw json data like so:

```
[{"day":"Monday","hours":43,"date":"2019-12-23T14:38:08.2112312-05:00"},{"day":"Tuesday","hours":36,"date":"2019-12-24T14:38:08.2130238-05:00"},{"day":"Wednesday","hours":39,"date":"2019-12-25T14:38:08.2130318-05:00"},{"day":"Thursday","hours":34,"date":"2019-12-26T14:38:08.2130329-05:00"},{"day":"Friday","hours":42,"date":"2019-12-27T14:38:08.2130338-05:00"}]
```

What I don't understand is why VUE.js is failing with a `"TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."` JSON is being surved for localhost use, and cors has been enabled. Any get request from postman, browser, curl, etc works just fine. It's only failing when VUE.js makes the fetch() call.

The VUE component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <LineChart v-if="loaded" :chartdata="chartdata" :options="options" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from './LineChart.vue';

export default {
  name: 'LineChartContainer',
  components: { LineChart },
  data: () => ({
    loaded: false,
    chartdata: null,
  }),
  async mounted() {
    this.loaded = false;
    try {
      const { daysWorked } = await fetch(
        'https://localhost:5001/api/timeworked',
      );
      console.log('days worked data:', daysWorked);
      this.chartdata = daysWorked;
      this.loaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Couldn't access data:", e);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Any thoughts, advice, or tips appreciated!

Comment: Is your localhost / dev env set up to support `https`?

Comment: @AndrewNolan it certainly is, although I tried disabling to no luck as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem with Vue. It's a problem with the way you fetch.

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

try

```js
...
const { daysWorked } = await fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/timeworked')
                                 .then(r=>r.json());
...
```

this should help.

Comment: try adding fetch(
        'https://localhost:5001/api/timeworked',{mode:'cors'}
      )

or 'no-cors' idk how your server is configured. Also take a look at the DevTools network tab for a clue what causing a problem.

Comment: Actually it's just missing the () on the json method.  So r.json() did the trick, thank you.